# T-SQL Trigger Update with conditions

Tags: t-sql, triggers

is it possible to block an update of a field based on a condition?

I have a table: sizes

| article | shoe_type | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shoes | 0 | 0 |
| pants | null | 0 |
| outerwear | null | 0 |

If the article is "shoes" and "shoe_type" is 0, it cannot be saved if the value 0 is not changed first. (0 must not remain)

If the article is "shoes" and "sizes" is 0, it cannot be saved if the value 0 is not changed first. (0 must not remain)

If the article is "pants" and "sizes" is 0, it cannot be saved if the value 0 is not changed first. (0 must not remain)

If the article is "outerwear" and "sizes" is 0, it cannot be saved if the value 0 is not changed first. (0 must not remain).

Comment: Is trigger a necessity? If not, just use check constraint (inline or with UDF). That only works if the checked values are in the same table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Check

Comment: the block on the update must be present when someone updates the data. (therefore it must not be possible to leave 0). the record with the value 0 is already present in the table.

Comment: Aside: When you write your trigger don't forget that it will fire once per _statement_, not _row_, i.e. if a single `update` affects 5 rows then the trigger will fire once with `inserted` and `deleted` containing 5 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
create trigger sizes__shoe_stuff
after update
as begin

if exists
(
    select
    from 
        inserted i
        inner join deleted d on i.article=d.article -- I assume article is the PK. If not, join i and d on all PK columns
    where
    (
            (d.article='shoes'      and d.shoe_type=0   and i.shoe_type <>0)
        or  (d.article in ('shoes','pants','outerwear') and d.size=0 and i.size <>0)
    )
)
throw 'Trigger error, value 0 must change'


end
```